# What large cardinal axioms does the point of first difference between elementary embeddings satisfy?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Let $j,k:V_{\lambda}\rightarrow V_{\lambda}$ be inequivalent elementary embeddings. Then let $\theta(j,k)$ be the largest limit ordinal $\gamma$ such that $j(x)\cap V_{\gamma}=k(x)\cap V_{\gamma}$ for all $x\in V_{\gamma}$. Then what large cardinal axioms must $\theta(j,k)$ satisfy? Is $\theta(j,k)$ necessarily a rank-into-rank cardinal? If not, then what large cardinal axioms must $\theta(j,k)$ satisfy? What happens if $j,k$ are some other sort of large cardinal embeddings rather than rank-into-rank embeddings?

The motivation behind this question is that $\equiv^{\theta(j,k)}$ and
$\equiv^{\theta(j,k)+\omega}$ will be inequivalent congruences on the algebras of rank-into-rank embeddings (recall that $j\equiv^{\gamma}k$ iff $j(x)\cap V_{\gamma}=k(x)\cap V_{\gamma}$ for $x\in V_{\gamma}$), so it would be good to know whether $\theta(j,k)$ is just some critical point of some rank-into-rank embedding or not. In many cases, $\theta(j,k)$ is the critical point of a rank-into-rank embedding. In particular, if $j,k\in\langle l\rangle$ for some $l:V_{\lambda}\rightarrow V_{\lambda}$, then $\theta(j,k)$ is the critical point of some rank-into-rank embedding.